# How to update tikz properly, or how to revert what I did

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, updating

I used to be able to compile the following LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,plotmarks} % even simpler

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
\end{document}
```

However, I noticed I was using tikz 1.68, so I have tried to update tikz to version 2.1. Now, this example won't work, the error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.875 \pgfsetsnakesegmenttransformation
{\pgf@snake@mirror\pgf@snake@raise}
```

In order to update tikz, I downloaded [pgf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) as a pgf_2.10.tds.zip file, extracted it in /usr/share/texmf/, replaced the old files, and ran texhash.

What went wrong?

Comment: The error arises with the simple example above. Just `\usepackage{tikz}` triggers the error.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. Then indeed, there is an installation issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was not to remove the old directory before installing the new version.

```
> diff -r /user/wok/home/Downloads/pgf/tex/generic/ /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/

Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer: pgfbaseimage.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer: pgfbaselayers.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer: pgfbasepatterns.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer: pgfbaseplot.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer: pgfbaseshapes.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer: pgfbasesnakes.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer: pgfcoremath.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer: tikz.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibraryshapes.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikz3d.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikzarrows.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikzautomata.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikzbackgrounds.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikzer.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikzmindmap.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikzpatterns.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikzpetri.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikzplothandlers.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikzplotmarks.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikzshapes.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikzsnakes.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikztopaths.code.tex
Only in /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries: pgflibrarytikztrees.code.tex
```